# DIgisol Wireless USB dongle is not working in UBUNTU 12.10

Tags: 12.10

Hi am using Lenovo and have installed UBuntu 12.10. the dongle detects the wireles network. when i enter the password... it connects but after sometime it shows again Authentication is Required by wireless network.The same password works in Windows 7. Please help me. Am very much new to UBUNTU. :)

Answer (score 0):

Digisol is not getting connected in my Ubuntu, even I after installed the scripts provided by the device, it is showing connection profile but is not getting connected.Some times it is showing Registered in Network but immediately disconnecting.Also, device is not getting detected immediately after attaching the device to the system

Comment: this reply was written by me at that time... I don't even remember it...the irony is that I've just come to this page through google search searching for the same problem........